# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\register.php on line 19

Tags: php, html, sql, phpmyadmin, web-development-server

I have received:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '5538ac14bb2ca7514f9f4d8826f3c45e'')' at line 1' in C:\xampp\htdocs\register.php:19 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\register.php(19): PDO->exec('insert into use...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\register.php on line 19.

How can this be solved, like what should be done?

```
<?php
    session_start();

    // If the form has been submitted

    if (isset($_POST['submitted'])){

        // Create a database connection

        $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=johnsoa7_db;host=localhost", "root", "");
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        // Get and sanitise the inputs, we don't need to do
        // this with the password as we hash it anyway

        $safe_forename = $db->quote($_POST['forename']);
        $safe_lastname = $db->quote($_POST['lastname']);
        $safe_email = $db->quote($_POST['email']);
        $hashed_password = $db->quote(md5($_POST['password']));

        // Insert the entry into the database

        $query = "insert into users values (default, $safe_forename, $safe_lastname, $safe_email, '$hashed_password')";

        $db->exec($query);

        // Get the ID

        $id = $db->lastInsertId();

        // Output success or the errors

        echo "Congratulations! You are now registered. Your ID is: $id";
    }
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php "If you are using [`PDO::quote()`] to build SQL statements, you are strongly recommended to use `PDO::prepare()` to prepare SQL statements with bound parameters instead of using `PDO::quote()` to interpolate user input into an SQL statement. Prepared statements with bound parameters are not only more portable, more convenient, immune to SQL injection, but are often much faster to execute than interpolated queries, as both the server and client side can cache a compiled form of the query."

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in this line:

```
$query = "insert into users values (default, $safe_forename, $safe_lastname, $safe_email,'$hashed_password')";
```

`default` should be quoted if it is string.

If it is a variable, you missed `$`.

Please see the comment by @ceejayoz:

As he said you don't need quoted around $hashed_password...

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried both methods and it still ceases to function. The error I have is:$db->exec($query); Do you know how to help with this please?

Comment: @AbrahamJohnson That's not an error, that's a line of code. v Sugumar is probably correct you need quotes around the `default` bit. You probably *don't* want the quotes around `$hashed_password` because `PDO::quote` adds them for you, so you've probably doubled up on them. You **really** don't want to be using MD5 for password hashing, by the way.

Comment: as @ceejayoz said you don't need to quotes around $hashed_password, that's the exact problem.. not my solution.. since default will be automatically converted to string.. if there is no constant in that name